# how to draw each row of a data Fram?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a data set with this columns:

```
   skill c1 c2 c3
    A   2   1   1
    B   8   4   9
    D   5   3   3
    H   0   7   7
    L   0   9   0
```

How I can plot each element in `skill`? For example the graph of  `A` is a 2 ,1,1 it can be scatter or bar chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.plot.bar(x='skill')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have 5021 rows